# changing maven cargo plugin deployment path

Tags: maven, cargo, maven-cargo

I want to have my integration test hit cargo's tomcat at http://localhost:8080/messaging but cargo (cargo-maven2-plugin:1.0.5) prefers to deploy my messaging project as /messaging-0.0.7-SNAPSHOT, as seen in the tomcat admin console and in the target\tomcat6x\webapps directory.

So I tried adding these lines to the cargo config, figuring that it will pick up the default artifact:

```
 <deployer>
  <deployables>
   <deployable>
     <properties>
     <context>/messaging</context>
    </properties>
   </deployable>
  </deployables>
 </deployer>
```

but it doesn't. It doesn't even attempt to since I don't see the messaging or messaging-0.0.7-SNAPSHOT in the target\tomcat6x\webapps directory.

The same thing happens when I set it up like so:

```
<configuration>
  <type>standalone</type>
 <wait>false</wait>
 <properties>
  <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
  <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>
 </properties>
 <deployer>
  <deployables>
   <deployable>
     <groupId>com.company.platform</groupId>
     <artifactId>messaging</artifactId>
     <type>war</type>
     <properties>
     <context>/messaging</context>
    </properties>
   </deployable>
  </deployables>
 </deployer>
</configuration>
```

Here's the full plugin config:

```
  <plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
<artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
 <execution>
  <id>start</id>
  <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
  <goals>
   <goal>start</goal>
  </goals>
 </execution>
 <execution>
  <id>stop</id>
  <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
  <goals>
   <goal>stop</goal>
  </goals>
 </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
  <type>standalone</type>
 <wait>false</wait>
 <properties>
  <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
  <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>
 </properties>
 <deployer>
  <deployables>
   <deployable>
     <properties>
     <context>/messaging</context>
    </properties>
   </deployable>
  </deployables>
 </deployer>
</configuration>
```

My integration test looks like this:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.sql.Time;

public class WebappTest extends TestCase
{
    public void testCallIndexPage() throws Exception
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/messaging/");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        assertEquals(200, connection.getResponseCode());
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(connection.getContent().getClass());

    }
}
```

What's the best way to proceed? Knowing that it will successfully deploy as hxxp://localhost:8080/messaging-0.0.7-SNAPSHOT, I could alter the test, but what would be a quick way to pull the artifact version in?

Ideally, I'd like to have cargo deploy it correctly, but it is unclear how.

Answer (score 2):

From [Cargo Plugin Reference](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+Plugin+Reference+Guide),

```
About WAR contexts

    Many containers have their specific files for redefining context roots (Tomcat 
has context.xml, JBoss has jboss-web.xml, etc.). If your WAR has such a file, the 
server will most probably use the context root defined in that file instead of the 
one you specify using the CARGO deployer.
```

Could you be hitting this issue?

Also, I think context name should not have a leading `/`.

Comment: That wasn't it. There is a web.xml but not a context.xml

Answer (score 2):

`Deployables` tag should not go inside `Deployer` tag:

```
  <deployables>
   <deployable>
     <properties>
     <context>/messaging</context>
    </properties>
   </deployable>
  </deployables>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about setting the finalName property?

If you set `<finalName>messaging</finalName>` in your POM this should do the trick.